# How to manage eclipse project on remote computer; ssh, ftp?

Tags: php, eclipse

Usually I'm creating project work space on my localhost (win). As soon as my code is tested I'm committing it into repository.

But some days ago I've faced a little difficulty. My customer want me to write code right on his server because he have some handmade binaries working only on his machine (solaris). I really don't know what to do. I've tried Eclipse plugin for connecting to remote servers, but **I'm still unable to create remote project**.

Any ideas?

PS: Sorry for my English :)

Thank you.

Comment: Was Target Management one of those plug-ins you tried? http://www.eclipse.org/dsdp/tm/, http://wiki.eclipse.org/TM_and_RSE_FAQ, http://live.eclipse.org/node/567

Comment: Exactly, but I couldn't figure out how to create eclipse projects using RSE (remote system explorer). Yes, I can manage files through ftp or sftp, but eclipse can't manage them as project. I even can't get code assisting from eclipse :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need a plugin to accomplish your goal. The following tutorial is aimed at Zend Studio, but I believe the information is generic enough that you can use it with just Eclipse: http://kb.zend.com/index.php?View=entry&EntryID=414